# Chromium Edge - Javascript seems to be affected by automatic checks for Edge updates

Tags: microsoft-edge

We have a single page web application.  One of the functions of the application is to supervise the connection path from the client back to the server.  This is implemented with a periodic ajax http request in javascript to the server every 60 seconds.  This request acts as a heartbeat.

After a session is started, the server looks for that heartbeat.  If it fails to receive a heartbeat request after a reasonable amount of time, it takes specific action.

The client also looks for a response to that heartbeat request.  If it fails to receive a response after a reasonable amount of time, it displays a message on the screen via javascript.

We are getting reports from the field where a Chrome version of Edge is failing.  Communication between the client and server is apparently failing.  The server is seeing those heartbeat requests cease – and taking that specific action.  However, the client is not taking the expected action on its side.  It’s not displaying the message indicating a failed heartbeat request.  It’s almost appears as though the javascript stopped running altogether.

The thing is, though…  The customer has reported that if they disable automatic updates to Microsoft Edge the application runs fine.  If the checking of updates is allowed to occur, the application eventually fails as described above.  Note that this is apparently happening when Edge is just checking for updates - it's already up to date.

Updates are being turned off using several guid-named registry keys at [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\EdgeUpdate].

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is there any error showing in console when the JavaScript stopped running? It could be better that you can provide [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can **reproduce the issue**. In that situation, we can have a test and try to debug. With only the above text description, it's hard to locate the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Yu Zhou.

That's a really good idea re the console.  I will pass that along.

I understand re a minimal code snippet - it's worth a thousand words...  Unfortunately, we're not able to reproduce this inhouse.  Being a SPA there's alot of javascript running; it'd be hard to boil it down to a meaningful snippet.

Comment: However, the application has been quite stable for several years.  It's been in the field for over 10 years.  This problem just popped up when the customer switched its userbase from IE to Edge.  And, while it does appear to be happening to multiple users, it's not every user.  In fact, we know of two users where it happens to one and not the other; even when they use the same machine.   They log into Windows through a domain, each using their own account.  We've also heard reports where uninstalling and reinstalling Edge has made the problem go away.  A real head scratcher...

Comment: According to your description, it looks like the issue might be related with the environment settings of different accounts. You can compare the environment of the working account and the not working one to see which difference leads to the issue. You can also compare the settings between working Edge and not working Edge, this can help to narrow down the issue.